# Nested For Loop and nltk.FreqDist - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by, nltk

I'm getting this error when doing a nested for loop - can anyone point out what is wrong?

my aim is for each combination of `cat` and `bt` and `session_Start_date` and `CSAT_flag` , to calculate the bigram word frequencies.

I am using for-loops to reduce chances of `MemoryError` - i can technically run this line of code without the for-loops, but will get a memoryError due to the sheer number of rows . the for-loop helps to do this in bitesize chunks

EDIT 1: i added some print statements to debug, turns out it is actually running for quite a few iterations on both loops, and the error comes mid way through looping

```
dict_of_df_bigr = {} 

for cat in df_seq_dedup.first_cat.unique():
    print(cat)
    for bt in df_seq_dedup.bu_tag.unique():
        print(bt)
        dict_of_df_bigr["df_{first_cat}_{butag}".format(first_cat=cat,butag=bt)]=df_seq_dedup[(df_seq_dedup.first_cat==cat)&(df_seq_dedup.bu_tag==bt)].groupby(['first_cat','bu_tag','session_start_date','CSAT_flag'])['lem_text'].apply(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist(nltk.bigrams(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(' '.join(x))))).dropna()
        print("df_{first_cat}_{butag} is DONE".format(first_cat=cat,butag=bt))
```

EDIT 2:
adding the traceback and error in full :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-8131c22d988b> in <module>
     15     for bt in df_seq_dedup.bu_tag.unique():
     16         print(bt)
---> 17         dict_of_df_bigr["df_{first_cat}_{butag}".format(first_cat=cat,butag=bt)]=df_seq_dedup[(df_seq_dedup.first_cat==cat)&(df_seq_dedup.bu_tag==bt)].groupby(['first_cat','bu_tag','session_start_date','CSAT_flag'])['lem_text'].apply(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist(nltk.bigrams(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(' '.join(x))))).dropna()
     18         print("df_{first_cat}_{butag} is DONE".format(first_cat=cat,butag=bt))
     19 #[test]concat the dicontary of pandas series/df

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    222     )
    223     def apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
--> 224         return super().apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
    225 
    226     @Substitution(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    733         with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
    734             try:
--> 735                 result = self._python_apply_general(f)
    736             except TypeError:
    737                 # gh-20949

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    752 
    753         return self._wrap_applied_output(
--> 754             keys, values, not_indexed_same=mutated or self.mutated
    755         )
    756 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _wrap_applied_output(self, keys, values, not_indexed_same)
    431             # if self.observed is False,
    432             # keep all-NaN rows created while re-indexing
--> 433             result = result.stack(dropna=self.observed)
    434             result.name = self._selection_name
    435             return result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in stack(self, level, dropna)
   6249             return stack_multiple(self, level, dropna=dropna)
   6250         else:
-> 6251             return stack(self, level, dropna=dropna)
   6252 
   6253     def explode(self, column: Union[str, Tuple]) -> "DataFrame":

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py in stack(frame, level, dropna)
    541         # we concatenate instead.
    542         dtypes = list(frame.dtypes.values)
--> 543         dtype = dtypes[0]
    544 
    545         if is_extension_array_dtype(dtype):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

EDIT 3: adding sample data of the `df_seq_dedup` dataframe and info about it

```
first_cat|  bu_tag    |session_start_date|  CSAT_flag
cat1     |bu_tag_1_ap   |2021-10-30      |noscore
cat1     |bu_tag_2a_ap  |2021-10-30      |noscore
cat2     |bu_tag_3z_ap  |2021-10-30      |DSAT
cat2     |NaN           |2021-10-30      |noscore
cat3     |bu_tag_4b_ap  |2021-10-30      |CSAT


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 284170 entries, 0 to 1394594
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------              --------------   ----- 
 0   first_cat           283776 non-null  object
 1   bu_tag              184016 non-null  object
 2   session_start_date  284170 non-null  object
 3   CSAT_flag           284170 non-null  object
 4   lem_text            284170 non-null  object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 13.0+ MB
```

EDIT4 : found the first error to happen when the data `lem_text` is string is  'funding' and for a particular first_cat and bu_Tag i just have 1 row as follows:

```
first_cat|  bu_tag    |session_start_date|  CSAT_flag |lem_text
cat5     |bu_tag_5_ap   |2021-10-30      |noscore     | funding
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback. I don't see any lists

Comment: added the traceback

Comment: share a reduceable sample of the data

Comment: sorry what do you mean by reducable sample ? do you mean a small sample of the  raw data in `df_seq_dedup` dataframe

Comment: added some raw data and info about the dataframe

Comment: what is lem_text?

Comment: lem_text is a free text field - can't share exact info given confidentiality, but it is free text from users that contain alphanuermic, punctuation , any character basically

Comment: i added the exact row and all data columns of the raw data  where the loop is throwing the error